# Add tailwindcss to default create-react-app template without change react-script run command

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, tailwind-css

I want to use `tailwindcss` UI with a default `create-react-app` template project.

in `package.json` I have access only to add dependencies & devDependencies, & I am not allowed to change the default `start` & `build` scripts commands which used by `react-scripts`.

my Question is: there a way to add  tailwind library to this template without changing the scripts commands in `package.json`

**note**: I can make changes in `webpack`, `postcss` config & add any file if required.

Comment: Did you read this ? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: @AhmetZeybek yes I read it, all described solutions in the installation docs refer to change in the scripts commands. by changing the use of the ```react-scripts``` command.